# How can i find the minimum value in a list of number without using the min() method in python?

Tags: python, methods, min

I tried doing this looping through a for loop comparing every element in the list to each other but the way i did it only work if the number in the list are positive it does not work if they are all negative. does anyone how how i can do this?

Comment: Instead of `mini = 0` use `mini = scores[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
mini = scores[0]
```

instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Any of these will work:

```
sorted(scores)[0]
sorted(scores, reverse=True)[-1]
[s for s in scores if all(s<=i for i in scores)][0]

def getMin(L):
    answer = L[0]
    for i in L:
        if i < answer:
            answer = i
    return answer
getMin(scores)
```